# Como añadir imagen en directorio y ruta de imagen en BBDD. Proyecto Spring

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-mvc, spring-data

Estoy intentando realizar dos cosas en mi proyecto de Tienda Virtual Spring a través de un formulario **`.jsp`**:

1. Subir una imagen a un directorio de mi proyecto.
2. Guardar en una BBDD una entidad llamada Producto la cual posee una propiedad llamada "urlImagen" que se trata de un String con la ruta donde está almacenada la imagen del Producto.

El Error que me da es el siguiente:

> ```
> Validation failed for object='producto'. Error count: 1
> org.springframework.validation.BindException:
> org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
> Field error in object 'producto' on field 'urlImagen': rejected value
> [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile@a78c91f];
> codes
> [typeMismatch.producto.urlImagen,typeMismatch.urlImagen,typeMismatch.java.lang.String,typeMismatch];
> arguments
> [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable:
> codes [producto.urlImagen,urlImagen]; arguments []; default message
> [urlImagen]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of
> type
> 'org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile'
> to required type 'java.lang.String' for property 'urlImagen'; nested
> exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of
> type
> 'org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile'
> to required type 'java.lang.String' for property 'urlImagen': no
> matching editors or conversion strategy found]
> ```

Entiendo que se refiere a algo así como que deseo almacenar un objeto *MultipartFile* como si fuera un *String* por lo que deduzco que tengo un error a la hora de intentar almacenar la ruta de la imagen.

Muestro el jsp:

```
        <form:form action="save" method="POST" modelAttribute="producto" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h3>Agregar Producto</h3>   
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label><h5>Nombre:</h5> </label>
                    <form:input path="nombre"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label><h5>Precio: </h5></label>
                    <form:input path="precio"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <p><label><h5>Descripción:</h5> </label></p>
                    <form:textarea path="descripcion"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <p><h5>Categoría: </h5></p>
                    <p><h6>Telefonía</h6> <form:radiobutton path="categoria" value="telefonía"/>
                    <h6>Informática</h6> <form:radiobutton path="categoria" value="informática"/></p>
                    <p><h6>Imagen y Sonido</h6> <form:radiobutton path="categoria" value="imagenysonido"/>
                    <h6>Videojuegos</h6> <form:radiobutton path="categoria" value="videojuegos"/></p>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <p><h5>Agregar Imagen</h5></p>
                    <p><form:input type="file" path="urlImagen"/></p>
                </div>          
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <input type="submit" value="Guardar" class="btn btn-success">
            </div>
        </form:form>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Y el controlador con los métodos relacionados con el problema en sí:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/agregarproducto", method= RequestMethod.GET)
public String agregarProducto(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("producto", new ProductosEntity());
    return "agregar-producto";
}
@RequestMapping(value="/save", method= RequestMethod.POST)
public String save(
        @RequestParam("precio") double precio,
        @RequestParam("nombre") String nombre,
        @RequestParam("categoria") String categoria,
        @RequestParam("descripcion") String descripcion,
        @RequestParam("urlImagen") MultipartFile imagen,
        @ModelAttribute("producto") ProductosEntity producto) {
        String url = null;

    if (!imagen.isEmpty()) {

        Path directorioImagen = Paths.get("src//main//webapp//public/images");
        String rutaAbsoluta = directorioImagen.toFile().getAbsolutePath();
        
        try {

          // Tratamiento del archivo
            byte[] bytesImg = imagen.getBytes();
            Path rutaCompleta = Paths.get(rutaAbsoluta + "//"+ imagen.getOriginalFilename());
            Files.write(rutaCompleta,  bytesImg);
     
           // Obtención de la url para la propiedad urlImagen de la entidad
            url = "/public/images/"+imagen.getOriginalFilename();
            
            // Almacenamiento de la entidad en BBDD
            producto.setUrlImagen(url);
            producto.setNombre(nombre);
            producto.setCategoria(categoria);
            producto.setDescripcion(descripcion);
            producto.setPrecio(precio);
            
          // Llamo al método save() del servicio (de JpaRepository)
            ips.save(producto);

            System.out.println("Registro guardado correctamente");

        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("No se ha podido almacenar archivo");
        }
    }
        return "redirect:/productos";
}
```

Entiendo que el método `getOriginalFilename()` devuelve el nombre del archivo por lo que no entiendo el error en la conversión.

Estaré encantado si alguien me puede ofrecer algo de luz sobre este problema. Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolví el problema! Para ayudar a quien pueda tener el mismo problema que yo:

No debía recibir por parámetro en el método del controlador "@modelAttribute("producto") ProductosEntity producto" ya que estaba recibiendo los parámetros del objeto al mismo tiempo ("@RequestParam...etc).

El resto del método está correcto.

He realizado una modificación para hacerlo más limpio y más orientado al objeto eliminando los @RequestParam y recibiendo directamente el objeto en cuestión(lo he separado en capas de una manera más óptima, ya no trabajo directamente con el objeto Entity).

En el controlador:

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/agregarproducto", method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public String agregarProducto(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("producto", new ProductoDto());
        return "agregar-producto";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/save", method= RequestMethod.POST)
    public String save(@ModelAttribute("producto") ProductoDto productoDto) {

       /*
       * HE SEPARADO EN TRES CAPAS EL OBJETO PRODUCTO: ProductoDto, Producto y 
       * ProductoEntity.  Y he creado una clase mapper que convierte de una clase a otra.
       */

        Producto producto = mapper.fromDtoToDomain(productoDto);

        productosService.save(producto);

        return "redirect:/productos";
    }
```

Y en el servicio:

```
@Override
    @Transactional
    public void save(Producto producto) {

        Path directorioImagen = Paths.get("src//main//webapp//public/images");
        String rutaAbsoluta = directorioImagen.toFile().getAbsolutePath();

        try {
            byte[] imagen = producto.getImagen();
            Path rutaCompleta = Paths.get(rutaAbsoluta + "//"+ producto.getUrlImagen());
            Files.write(rutaCompleta,  imagen);
            String url = "/public/images/" + producto.getUrlImagen();

            ProductoEntity productoEntity = mapper.fromDomainToEntity(producto);
            productoEntity.setUrlImagen(url);

            productosRepository.save(productoEntity);
            System.out.println("Registro guardado correctamente");
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("No se ha podido almacenar archivo");
        }
    }
```